# SQL - Apply only one set of joins at a time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three joins in my query. My requirement is to select records if either first two joins get satisfied or the third join gets satisfied

```
select * from security.requestview r 
-- either below two joins satisfy
left join security.RequestDelegateView rd on r.id = rd.RequestId
join (select top 1 PersonnelNumber from SECURITY.MyRolesView) m on (m.PersonnelNumber=r.RequestorId or m.PersonnelNumber=r.InitiatorId or m.PersonnelNumber=rd.DelegatePersonnelNumber)

-- or this join 
join (select substring(ltrim(DDSUCode),0,3) as Division from security.staffview where PersonnelNumber = (select top 1 PersonnelNumber from SECURITY.MyRolesView)) s 
            on r.OrganizationUnitRefId like  s.Division+'%'
```

But ofcourse it will try to satisfy all the joins together.

Is there any way I can put some condition where it will select record if either first two joins satisfy or the last join alone satisfies?

Update

I tried putting them as where conditions but then the query is running forever

Comment: just do 3 left and 3 or in the where

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question:

> Is there any way I can put some condition where it will select record
>   if either first two joins satisfy or the last join alone satisfies?

No, I know of no way to do this in a single query.

One way you can write this so that the third join only gets executed if the first one doesn't return records is in a multi-query series that populates a temp table or table variable:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp 
SELECT (the first join);

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp) = 0
  INSERT INTO #tmp
  SELECT (the second join);

SELECT * FROM #tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH FirstJoin AS (
    select * from security.requestview r 
    left join security.RequestDelegateView rd on r.id = rd.RequestId
    join (select top 1 PersonnelNumber from SECURITY.MyRolesView) m on (m.PersonnelNumber=r.RequestorId or m.PersonnelNumber=r.InitiatorId or m.PersonnelNumber=rd.DelegatePersonnelNumber)

), SecondJoin AS (
    select * from security.requestview r 
    join (select substring(ltrim(DDSUCode),0,3) as Division from security.staffview where PersonnelNumber = (select top 1 PersonnelNumber from SECURITY.MyRolesView)) s 
                on r.OrganizationUnitRefId like  s.Division+'%'
), BothJoins AS (
    SELECT * FROM FirstJoin
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM SecondJoin
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM BothJoins
```

To get this to work you need to Change the "Select *" inside the CTE's so that every returned column is named. (Since I don't know whats in your tables I couldn't do it).

Please note that FirstJoin and SecondJoin needs to return the same columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table1
left join table2 
      on table1.id = table2.t1
left join table3 
      on table1.id = table3.t1
left join table4 
      on table1.id = table4.t1 
where table2.t1 is not null 
   or table3.t1 is not null
   or table4.t1 is not null
```